# Plot multiple axis aligned with gnuplot

Tags: time-series, gnuplot

I am trying to plot a time series on the left, and its histogram on the right. I have 10000 samples. The files ts.dat and hist.dat contains point to plot in the correct form. How can I plot the two axis aligned? With the code below, gnuplot aligns the canvas, and as the x labels are of different length the axis y length is different.

```
set term pngcairo font "Times New Roman, 8" size 640, 240
set out 'mp.png'
set multiplot
set tics out
set tics scale 0.5
unset key
set size .66, 1
set yrange[-6:6]
set xtics rotate by 45 right
set xlabel "Iteration no."
set ylabel "USD"
plot 'ts.dat' with lines
set origin .66, 0
set size .33, 1
set yrange [-6:6]
set format y ""
set style fill transparent solid 0.3
set xlabel "No. of occurences"
unset ylabel
plot 'hist.dat' using 2:1 with filledcurves
unset multiplot
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want to be different in that image?  The y axes look aligned to me, thanks to the matching `set yrange [-6:6]` calls.

Comment: the x axis on the right chart is below the x asis on the left chart since the y-axis on the right chart is slightly longer than the correspondant y-axis on the left.

Comment: Okay, I see it now.  The mis-alignment is pretty small in the image and I simply missed it upon first glance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `help margins`.

If you set a fixed bottom margin manually, e.g. `set bmargin 3` or `set bmargin at screen 0.1`, the bottom x-axes should be aligned in both plots.